# Is this unconditional sentence "If you do yoga every day, you will sleep better" wrong?

Tags: grammaticality, conditionals

According to this [Website](http://www2.estrellamountain.edu/faculty/stonebrink/ESL040/4_types_of_conditionals.htm):

There are 4 Types of Conditionals:

[image]

So, based on the above explanation, I think "*If you  do yoga every day, you  will sleep better*", which was copied from an English teaching material, is not a very accurate sentence.

I think the above sentence should be change to

Zero Conditional: *If you  do yoga every day, you sleep better* (remove "*will*")

or

1st Conditional: *If you  do yoga this evening, you will sleep better* (change "*every day*" to "*this evening*")

So, **am I wrong or right?**

Comment: Why do you think your example doesn't fit into First Conditional? Because of using *everyday*?

Comment: because "everyday" is to say about something happens repeatedly and thus is suitable for Zero conditional

Comment: Even though there are adverbs or adverbial phrases which go better with a certain type of sentences, adverbs or adverbial phrases never determine any sentence.

Comment: "Accurate" implies that it is technically correct, which is a medical issue, not a linguistic one.  There is nothing wrong with the syntax or semantics.

Answer (score 1):

The website linked to in the question has the title *The 4 Types of Conditionals* and includes the table shown here. The only text on the web page (with the exception of numerous links to various practice quizzes) is the claim that:

> Conditional sentences have two clauses:  a condition (if...) and a
>   result.  The verb tenses used in each clause depends on whether the
>   speaker thinks the result is probable (real) or only exists in the
>   imagination (unreal).

While the table shows four very common combinations of verb forms in the two clauses of conditional statements, these are far from being the only possibilities of constructing *if-statements* - contrary to the implication in the page title.

Furthermore, the semantic associations of the four constructions (shown in the left column of the table - and as summarized in the source text) are simplistic, and only partially reflect real English usage.

It would be better, therefore, not to base judgments on the grammaticality of *if-constructions* on the very short overview presented by the website you link to.

As to the example in the question, you are wrong to think that *If you do yoga every day, you will sleep better* is "*not a very accurate sentence*" and should be changed.

Your reasoning seems to be based on the erroneous belief that the term "*every day*" refers only to the present and thus cannot be used in a "*first conditional*".

In fact, "*every day*" can very well refer to the future, i.e. *every day from now on*. It would be very natural, for example, for a doctor to tell a patient suffering from insomnia: 
*"If you do yoga every day, you will sleep better."*